# Need a algorithm to find the minimum cost in a subset of elements

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, linear-programming

I am trying to find an optimal algorithm that can find the largest subset where the sum of the  elements is the lowest while covering all elements.

eg :- Imagine A B C are retailers and W X Y Z are products, the goal is to minimize the visits, and lower the price.

```
    A    B    C
W   4    9    2  
X   1    3    4 
Y   9    3    9
Z   7    1    1 

So it appears my top two choices are 
a) B:{XYZ} - 7   C:{W} - 2
b) C:{WXZ} - 7   B:{Y} - 3 

So a) is picked because since it has a lower cost, i.e 9.
```

This problem seems similar to vertex cover and other linear programming algorithms, but I can't figure out the right one.

Update:

It seems I need to add an additional variable. Introducing t. If the cost of visiting fewest retailers and the next fewest is > t, the next former is picked.

```
Continuing with the example.

say t = 5,

The largest subset containing all elements would be B:{WXYZ} with a cost of 16. 
The next largest subset(s) is B:{XYZ} - 7   C:{W} - 2 with a cost of 9. 

t = 16 - 9 > 5. So we pick B:{XYZ} - 7   C:{W} - 2 

but if we did A:{X}, B:{Y}, C:{WZ} - 5, t = 9 - 5 < 5. 

So B:{XYZ} - 7   C:{W} - 2 is picked
```

Really I'm just interested if there is already an algorithm that fits this pattern. I can't be the first person that needs this sort of optimization.

Comment: Hrmm, considered using a tree and maybe depth first search? Been a while since I've done this sort of thing, seems like it could work though.

Comment: What is the tradeoff between minimising price and minimising visits. Do you want to find, for the lowest price, the minimum number of visits that satisfies that?

Comment: The problem seems looks like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_theory_(mathematics)

Comment: I do not understand the question, and the example confuses me.  Please explain why `C:{WXYZ}` (fewer visits) or `A:{X}, B:{Y}, C:{WZ}` (lower cost) could not be picked instead of `B:{XYZ}, C:{W}`.

Comment: Maybe he wants the pareto frontier? (The set of solutions such that there exists no solution that is better in both criteria.) Doesn't seem like it though.

Comment: It would help if you defined a cost function for the number of retailers visited. For example, what makes your example cost of 9 visiting 2 retailers better than a cost of 7 visiting all 3 retailers or a cost of 16 visiting only one?

Comment: @btilly, A:{X}, B:{Y}, C:{WZ} would have a better cost but would involve visiting one more retailer, ie A.

Comment: thanks for trying to help everyone. I've made edits to the original to clarify it the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with two objectives - 1. to minimize the total lower cost of the products and also to 2. minimize the number of stores visited. (The comment by @btilly rightly shows two competing solutions.)

Multiple objectives are fairly common in these types of Integer programming problems. [See MCDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-criteria_decision_analysis).
To resolve this, you need to have *two* types of costs (you currently have only one.)

1. The cost of buying product p from retailer r (which you have specified) `C_rp`
2. The cost of visiting a retailer: `C_r`

Intuition: If C_r is very high, then we'll buy all the products from one retailer. If C_r is small, then we go to multiple retailers and buy from whomever is selling it most inexpensively.

Your problem can be modeled as a variant of the "[Assignment Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)." Also, read up on the so-called `fixed-charge transportation problems` (FCTP) if you need more references. (There is a fixed charge to visiting a retailer once.)

So on to the Integer programming formulation:

**Decision Variables**

```
  Binary
  X_rp = if product p is purchased from retailer r, 0 otherwise 
  Y_r = 1 if retailer r is visited, 0 otherwise
```

**Objective Function**

```
 Min C_rp X_rp + C_r Y_r
```

**Constraints**

```
(Sum over r) X_rp = 1 for all p (Every product must be bought from some retailer)
```

Next, we need to ensure that Y_r is one if even one of the X_rp is 1 for for that retailer. Normally, we'd resort to the Big M method, but it is easier in this problem.

```
X_rp <= Y_r  for all p, for all r.
```

If any of the X variables becomes 1, that forces the Y_r to become 1. The model will pay the price C_r.

To solve, you can use any LP solver. The good news is that problem has an integrality property, meaning that integer solutions naturally occur even when linear programming solution techniques are used.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The assignment problem does have a totally unimodular LP, but the LP with new constraints is not TU, which is not surprising given the existence of an objective-preserving reduction from set cover.

Comment: I would call this problem non-metric facility location. I agree with your choice of integer programming as a solution method.