# Integer linear programming to minimize cost over ranges

Tags: linear-programming

I'm stuck on this ILP problem..

We have a person wanting to travel between points `start->end` on a real axis. Along the way, they can take public transport. Each public transport method, `i`, has a range `[a_i,b_i]` and a cost `c_i`. The person can enter at any time between `[a_i,b_i]` and leave at any point `x` in `[x, b_i]`. We want to minimize the total cost. We want an integer linear programming solution to solve this, with a finite amount of constraints.

We just need to minimize the cost and doesn't need to worry about finding the locations to board/exit.

To me, this sort of sounds like some subset problem. Because, we basically want to get the longest public transport option at the lowest cost, or the combination of them that has the lowest cost and goes the farthest. Though I'm not quite sure on how to get started on formulating it. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: This is an equivalent problem - [Need a algorithm to find the minimum cost in a subset of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312261/need-a-algorithm-to-find-the-minimum-cost-in-a-subset-of-elements)

Comment: Also, this question right now is highly opinion-based (i.e., "what algorithm should I use?"). In the future, you should ask questions about specific fixes to algorithms you already have - see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)